# Drawing Cards at Random

Tags: probability, combinatorics

**Situation**

We have $10$ cards, with $7$ blacks and $3$ reds. Draw $3$ cards at random.

**Exercise**

(1) What is the probability that at least one of the cards is black if we have sampling with replacement?

(2) What is the probability that at least one of the cards is black if we have sampling without replacement?

**My attempt**

The complementary quantity of at least one black card is zero black cards, which is equal to $3$ red cards.

(1) We have the following with replacement:

\begin{align}
P(\geq 1~\text{black})
&= 1-P(0~\text{black})\\
&= 1-P(3~\text{red})\\
&= 1-\frac{3}{10}\cdot\frac{3}{10}\cdot\frac{3}{10}\\
&= \frac{973}{1000}.
\end{align}

(2) We have the following without replacement:

\begin{align}
P(\geq 1~\text{black})
&= 1-P(0~\text{black})\\
&= 1-P(3~\text{red})\\
&= 1-\frac{3}{10}\cdot\frac{2}{9}\cdot\frac{1}{8}\\
&= \frac{714}{720}.
\end{align}

**Question**

Is my attempt correct? If it's not, what is the right way of doing it?

Comment: Assuming there are no calculation errors, it's correct.

Comment: yep this is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, these calculations are correct. For the second probability, if you give an answer as a fraction, it's nice to give it in lowest terms:
$$
\frac{714}{720} = \frac{119}{120}.
$$